# Magento1 redirect issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this method

```
public function createParticipantAction(){
  ...
  $checkData = $this->validateData($data);
  if($checkData==true){
     $this->_redirect('course/participant/create');
     exit();
  }
  ...
}

public function validateData($data){
if($data){
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $validateData = Mage::getModel('course/participant');
    $validateData->addData($data);
    $name = $validateData->getName();
    if($name==''){
        $session->addError('Name Error');
    }
    return true;
 }
  return false;
```

}

When calling $this->validateData($data), if the name is null, it will exit and redirect to the registration page. But right now it doesn't work.

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$checkData = $this->validateData($data);
  if($checkData==false){
     $this->_redirect('course/participant/create');
     return;
  }
```

&

```
public function validateData($data){

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $validateData = Mage::getModel('course/participant');
    if($data['name']==''){
        $session->addError('Name Error');
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you devidas

Answer (score 0):

exit() will stop execution so the redirect part will not work.

Please try to use exit() after the redirect, like this:

```
public function validateData($data){

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $validateData = Mage::getModel('course/participant');
    $validateData->addData($data);
    $name = $validateData->getName();
    if($name==''){
        $session->addError('Name Error');
        $this->_redirect('course/participant/create');
        exit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Toan Tam. Can i chat with you in skype?